# Formula for the sum of fractions

Tags: summation, transformation

How to find the formula for the sum of fractions like this?
$$\frac{1}{1\times 2}+\frac{1}{2\times 3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n\times (n+1)}=$$

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 2):

You can write $\dfrac 1{n(n+1)} = \dfrac 1n  - \dfrac 1{n+1}$.  You get a lot of cancellation after which the expression equals $1 - \dfrac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Did you seriously think that this question was never asked here before?

Comment: To be honest I didn't give it a thought one way or another. Am I being naughty or something?

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}$$ for all $k$, you sum telescopes to 
$$1 - \frac{1}{n+1}.$$